# Spreadsheet to MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, export

I need to export spreadsheet data for import into a MySQL database. Data must be in quotes to import properly. The problem is with numbers. Is there a formula or other quick method other than copy and paste to convert numerical data to text in a column?

Or, am I going about this all wrong because there's a better way to get all cell data enclosed in quote marks for export to CSV?

Comment: can't you just use `optionally enclosed by '"'` in the command you use to load the csv?

Comment: Could you select the column, copy it, and then paste it as plaintext to the new column? Then you can select the new column and use that when you export the table.